# Text Asset for a word making game is not being read in unity run time properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I was making a bookworm like game for a school thesis and I had a weird problem where for some reason, the code and unity returns the array of the text asset as zero.

here was the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Data;

public class WordChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] validWords;
    private Row row;
    private string word;
    private List<LetterDragTiles> droppedTiles = new List<LetterDragTiles>();
    

    public int EnemyMaxHealth;
    public int EnemyCurrentHealth;
    public int PlayerMaxHealth;
    public int PlayerCurrentHealth;
    public int amount;
    public int HostileAmount;

    [SerializeField] GameObject panel;

    private void Awake()
    {
        row = GetComponentInChildren<Row>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        LoadData();
        EnemyCurrentHealth = EnemyMaxHealth;
        PlayerCurrentHealth = PlayerMaxHealth;
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        TextAsset textFile = Resources.Load("Referentials") as TextAsset;
        string[] lines = textFile.text.Split("\n");
        Debug.Log(textFile.text);
        Debug.Log("Number of words in dictionary: " + validWords.Length);
        validWords = new string[lines.Length];
        for (int i =0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            validWords[i] = lines[i].Trim();
        }
        

    }
    public void AddDroppedTile(LetterDragTiles tile)
    {
        droppedTiles.Add(tile);
        UpdateRow();
    }

    private void UpdateRow()
    {
        // Clear existing tiles from the row
        foreach (var tile in row.tiles)
        {
            tile.SetLetter(' ');
        }

        // Add letters from dropped tiles to the row
        for (int i = 0; i < droppedTiles.Count; i++)
        {
            row.tiles[i].SetLetter(droppedTiles[i].LetterBlock);
        }
    }

    public void SubmitRow(Row row)
    {
        word = row.word;
        
        Debug.Log("Word formed: " + word);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        {
            Debug.Log("Please enter a word");
            return;
        }

        if (isValidWord(word))
        {

            EnemyCurrentHealth -= amount;
            if (EnemyCurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                LoadScene();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No such word");
            PlayerCurrentHealth -= HostileAmount;
            if (PlayerCurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                panel.SetActive(true);
            }
            
        }

    }

    private bool isValidWord(string word)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < validWords.Length; i++)
        {
            string validWord = validWords[i].Trim();
            if (validWord == word.Trim())
            {
                Debug.Log("Word exists");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("The word doesn't exist in the index");
        return false;
    }

    public void LoadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex+ 1);
    }
}
```

And when I tried to see it through debug.log, here is what it says:

> Number of words in dictionary: 0 UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> WordChecker:LoadData () (at Assets/Scripts/WordChecker.cs:43)
> WordChecker:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/WordChecker.cs:33)

Did I mess up somewhere? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are logging the `validWords` array before setting it in `LoadData()`.  Try moving the debug to after you populate the array.  Maybe you meant to use `lines.Length` in the debug.

Comment: Oh hey it worked, nice, thank you for the help. Well it also means that the problem in my game is a different matter XD